# How to read multi-level json

Tags: javascript, json

So, I know how to read a "single-level" json array.  However, I can't figure out how to index the value I want from a multi-level json array.

I have this JSON data:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "YouTube Developers Live: Embedded Web Player Customization"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to access the value of title, however neither of these access the value, but instead return undefined:

`console.log(data["items"][0].title);`

or:

`console.log(data["items"][0]["title"]);`

But, this code returns the `snippet` object:

`console.log(data["items"][0]);`

The `data` variable refers to the json data.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.items[0].snippet.title
```

Explanation (you can see corresponding object in `/* */` comment):

```
items[0];
/*
{
    'snippet': {
        'title': 'YouTube Developers Live: Embedded Web Player Customization'
    }
}
*/

items[0].snippet;
/*
{
    'title': 'YouTube Developers Live: Embedded Web Player Customization'
}
*/

items[0].snippet.title;
/*
'YouTube Developers Live: Embedded Web Player Customization'
*/
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  So was items[0] accessing the table that held snippet, er?

Comment: @Conash in addition to my answer, `data.items` is the same as `data["items"]`

Comment: Thank you! Explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

As addition to madox2's answer, here's an explanation:

```
{
    "items": [
      {
       "snippet": {
          "title": "YouTube Developers Live: Embedded Web Player Customization"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The root is a Object, while `items` is an array. Objects are surrounded by curly braces, while arrays are surrounded by sqare braces.

In JS, you can access a Object like this:

```
parent.child
```

In your case, assuming you the data is assigned to a variable called `data`, you would access it with the variable name and the object you want to get:

```
data.items
```

Array's have keys - if no keys are specified, the keys will be number-based.

So seeing that `items` is an array without any key specified, you'll have to access the x-th element. `x` is in your case 0, because it's the first item of the array (Remember, arrays are zero-indexed):

```
data.items[0]
```

And here you have a object again, so access it:

```
data.items[0].snippet.title
```