# How to create a multi-level json file and then read specific values from python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am working on a quiz style program for learning the Arabic language. I'm now at the point where I need to remove the questions from my code and store them in an external file - i'm thinking .JSON. I'm having difficulty however with accessing certain questions or parts of the file from python and I'm not sure if it's because I haven't formatted my .JSON file correctly or if there is an error with my code. I've included both below. Eventually I plan on having multiple lessons each with 3-4 parts per lesson full of questions in the .JSON file. Currently I just have one lesson with three parts just to make sure I'm doing things right. I've looked at another question here ([How to read multi-level json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182660/how-to-read-multi-level-json)) but the solutions didn't seem to work for me.

If I try and run the code right now I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/LearningArabic/Test Programs/JSON open file test.py", line 10, in <module>
print(data["lesson 1"]["part two"])
KeyError: 'part two'
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import random

with open("C:\\LearningArabic\\LiblibArriby\\Lessons\\Arabic_Lessons.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

for i in data["lesson 1"]["part one"]:
    print (i["question"])

print(data["lesson 1"]["part two"])

for i in data["lesson 1"][0]["part two"]:
    print (i["answer"])

question = (data["lesson 1"]["part one"])
questions = random.choice(question)

print(questions.get("question"))
```

The line:

```
for i in data["lesson 1"]["part one"]:
    print (i["question"])
```

works and prints all of the questions in part one but after that I get the aforementioned error.

Here is my .JSON file:

```
{"lesson 1":[
    {"part one": [
        {"question": "What is the meaning of 'واد' ?",
        "transliteration": "walid",
        "answer": "boy"
        },
        {"question": "What is the meaning of 'بنت' ?",
        "transliteration": "bint",
        "answer": "girl"
        },
        {"question": "What is the meaning of 'رخل' ?",
        "transliteration": "ragul",
        "answer": "man"
        },
        {"question": "What is the meaning of 'ست' ?",
        "transliteration": "sit",
        "answer": "woman"
        }
    ],
    "part two": [
        {"question": "What is the meaning of '2test1'?",
        "transliteration": "phonix",
        "answer": "21"
        },
        {"question": "What is the meaning of '2test2'?",
        "transliteration": "phonix2",
        "answer": "22"
        }
    ],
    "part three": [
        {"question": "What is the meaning of '3test1'?",
        "transliteration": "phonix",
        "answer": "31"
        },
        {"question": "What is the meaning of '3test2'?",
        "transliteration": "phonix2",
        "answer": "32"
        }
    ]}
]}
```

Comment: What about using a jsonl file? Than it will be pretty easy to do this.

Comment: I did use a json file, that was the last part of the question. I've included it here because I'm worried there might be a formatting error that is giving me the error message.

Comment: I was saying to use a jsonl file, different from json

Comment: @piethon26, what would be the benefit of a jsonl file vs a json file?

Comment: less nested, I guess I was just thinking of it because a jsonl is a json of jsons technically, so each line could be a json for the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JSON file:

```
{"lesson 1":
    {"part one": [
        {"question": "What is the meaning of 'ست' ?",
        "transliteration": "sit",
        "answer": "woman"
        }
    ],
    "part two": [
    ],
    "part three": [
        {"question": "What is the meaning of '3test2'?",
        "transliteration": "phonix2",
        "answer": "32"
        }
    ]}
}
```

with the following python code:

import json

```
with open("test.json", "r", encoding = "utf-8-sig") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

for i in data["lesson 1"]["part one"]:
    print (i["question"])

for i in data["lesson 1"]["part two"]:
    print (i["answer"])
```

works as expected. `print(data["lesson 1"]["part two"])` works as well.

You need to remove the square brackets after `"lesson1:` and sort out your indexing of the variables

Comment: No luck. I removed the "[" bracket after "lesson one" and got the same error. I then removed the "]" bracket all the way at the end (so all of the brackets would be closed) and still no luck. Is the code in my file correct?

Comment: Markus, this ended up working for me. I must have had a formatting error somewhere in my json.file but I stripped it down to just one question per part and then it worked (also removed the bracket). I then rebuilt the json.file with the other questions and now everything is working a expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it like this with nested loop:

```
for k in data["lesson 1"].keys():
    print(data["lesson 1"][k])
    for i in range(len(data["lesson 1"][k])):
        print(data["lesson 1"][k][i]["question"])
```

Output:

```
 [{'question': "What is the meaning of 'واد' ?", 'transliteration': 'walid', 'answer': 'boy'}, {'question': "What is the meaning of 'بنت' ?", 'transliteration': 'bint', 'answer': 'girl'}, {'question': "What is the meaning of 'رخل' ?", 'transliteration': 'ragul', 'answer': 'man'}, {'question': "What is the meaning of 'ست' ?", 'transliteration': 'sit', 'answer': 'woman'}]
    What is the meaning of 'واد' ?
    What is the meaning of 'بنت' ?
    What is the meaning of 'رخل' ?
    What is the meaning of 'ست' ?
    [{'question': "What is the meaning of '2test1'?", 'transliteration': 'phonix', 'answer': '21'}, {'question': "What is the meaning of '2test2'?", 'transliteration': 'phonix2', 'answer': '22'}]
    What is the meaning of '2test1'?
    What is the meaning of '2test2'?
    [{'question': "What is the meaning of '3test1'?", 'transliteration': 'phonix', 'answer': '31'}, {'question': "What is the meaning of '3test2'?", 'transliteration': 'phonix2', 'answer': '32'}]
    What is the meaning of '3test1'?
    What is the meaning of '3test2'?
```

Comment: Luca, this does work but it doesn't answer my question. I was having issues with the formatting in my json.file. It is a cool way to display sections of the json.file though.